# How to post new version file BIM 360 cloud model using Design Automation?

Tags: c#, autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

I have a problem when I'm try to update new parameter override to BIM 360 cloud Revit model and post a new publish version for Revit model,

Example: The latest version model in BIM 360 with file name `sample.rvt` is version `1` . After set parameter will be become the file name `sample.rvt` with version `2`.

These are the steps I'm tried to achieve :

- Create bundle app update parameters

  ```cs
  private void DoJob(DesignAutomationData data)
  {
      if(data.RevitDoc == null) throw new Exception("Have problem with DesignAutomationData.RevitDoc");
      Document doc = data.RevitDoc;
      List<InputParams> inputParams = GetParamsJson();
      string result = SetParameterCommand.Execute(doc, inputParams);
      File.WriteAllText("result.txt", result);
  }
  ```
- Create activity

  ```cs
  Activity activitySpec = new Activity()
  {
     // Activities 
     ... 
  }
  ```
- Execute work item

  ```cs
  private async Task<Status> ExecuteWorkItem(string forgeToken,List<InputParams> inputParams, string projectId, string versionId, string callBackUrl)
      ...
  ```
- Post new version - **I don't know how to implement this**

I failed with the last step, post new version, because I can't find any sample on GitHub for post new version from BIM360 Model just saved as file to bucket. If you have any C# code sample, I'd appreciate it if you shared it.

Comment: Can you try this blog - https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/uploading-file-bim360acc-design-automation-through-cli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I also have answer for my problem at this document:
https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/tutorials/document-management/upload-document-s3/

This is step by step I resolved my problem :

1. Create a new storage object
2. Check file item exist and use this item if it exit.

```
  var items = await GetFolderItems(projectId, folderUrn, accessToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
        var item = items.Cast<KeyValuePair<string, dynamic>>().FirstOrDefault(item =>
            item.Value.attributes.displayName.Equals(filename, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

3. Post a update version :

- In case item not exitss, we create a new one .
- In case item exites, keep use item id at previous version like `urn:adsk.wipprod:dm.lineage:J-CiZHzFTGy-A0-RfhEUMQ`:

```cs
 private static async Task<string> UpdateVersionAsync(string projectId, string itemId, string objectId,
        string filename, string accessToken)
    {
        var versionsApi = new VersionsApi();
        versionsApi.Configuration.AccessToken = accessToken;

        var relationships = new CreateVersionDataRelationships
        (
            new CreateVersionDataRelationshipsItem
            (
                new CreateVersionDataRelationshipsItemData
                (
                    CreateVersionDataRelationshipsItemData.TypeEnum.Items,
                    itemId
                )
            ),
            new CreateItemRelationshipsStorage
            (
                new CreateItemRelationshipsStorageData
                (
                    CreateItemRelationshipsStorageData.TypeEnum.Objects,
                    objectId
                )
            )
        );
        var createVersion = new CreateVersion
        (
            new JsonApiVersionJsonapi
            (
                JsonApiVersionJsonapi.VersionEnum._0
            ),
            new CreateVersionData
            (
                CreateVersionData.TypeEnum.Versions,
                new CreateStorageDataAttributes
                (
                    filename,
                    new BaseAttributesExtensionObject
                    (
                        "versions:autodesk.bim360:File",
                        "1.0",
                        new JsonApiLink(string.Empty),
                        null
                    )
                ),
                relationships
            )
        );

        dynamic versionResponse = await versionsApi.PostVersionAsync(projectId, createVersion).ConfigureAwait(false);
        var versionId = versionResponse.data.id;
        return versionId;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Check this code.

```
private void PostNewVersion(string forgeToken, string projectId, string itemId, string newVersion, string callbackUrl)
{
    RestClient client = new RestClient("https://developer.api.autodesk.com/data/v1/projects/" + projectId + "/versions");
    RestRequest request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
    request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + forgeToken);
    request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    
    // Prepare the request body with version details
    string requestBody = $"{{\"data\": {{\"type\": \"versions\",\"attributes\": {{\"name\": \"YourModelName\",\"extension\": {{\"type\": \"versions:autodesk.bim360:File\",\"version\": \"{newVersion}\"}}}},\"relationships\": {{\"item\": {{\"data\": {{\"type\": \"items\",\"id\": \"{itemId}\"}}}}}}}},\"jsonapi\": {{\"version\": \"1.0\"}}}}";
    request.AddParameter("application/json", requestBody, ParameterType.RequestBody);

    // Execute the request
    IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
    
    // Handle the response
    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Created)
    {
        // Version created successfully
        string versionId = response.Headers
            .FirstOrDefault(h => h.Name == "Location" && h.Value.ToString().Contains("versions"))
            ?.Value?.ToString();
        
        // Now, you can associate the storage location with the new version (not shown in this example)
        UpdateStorageLocation(forgeToken, projectId, versionId, callbackUrl);
    }
    else
    {
        // Handle error
        Console.WriteLine("Error creating version: " + response.Content);
    }
}

private void UpdateStorageLocation(string forgeToken, string projectId, string versionId, string callbackUrl)
{
    // Implement the logic to update storage location
    // Use the projects/:project_id/storage endpoint to associate the model with the new version
    // Refer to Forge Data Management API documentation for details
}
```

Comment: Although this code might answer the question, I recommend that you also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: It will won't work, I allway receive message is :  "detail": "[WIP] Another object with the same name already exists in this container"